# Spring @ComponentScan annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, spring-mongodb, component-scan

I have spring boot application sample with package layout:

```
main:
-com.foo
     Application.java       
-com.foo.services
      ItemService.java
      ItemRepository.java    
-com.foo.config
     Configuration.java
test:
-com.foo.services 
     ItemServiceIngegrationTest.java
```

My integration test fails to run being not able to find ItemRepository bean
if put

```
  @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ItemService.class })
```

but works if I put

```
  @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class })
```

**where is the trick  ?**

spec says :

> Either basePackageClasses() or basePackages() (or its alias value())
>   may be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific
>   packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the
>   class that declares this annotation.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Configuration.class })
public class ItemServiceIntegrationTest { 
    . . .
}

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ItemService.class })
public class Configuration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
   .  .  .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc says:

> **If specific packages are not defined**, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

So, it scans from the package that declares `ComponentScan` unless a specific package class is defined. Can you put it in the `Application` class?

Comment: It works if you define it as Application, which resides in a lower level package, but not if you define it in a higher level package. The package you define it as is the `parent` package and it scans all the `children` packages.

Comment: yes, i know it works with Application -  that what is stated in my description:).  My point that according to spec it should work even with sub-packages.

Comment: Yea, I agree. According to the documentation it seems that both your annotations should find the ItemRepository bean.